# Reading HTML from source map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, source-maps

I'm trying to get both Typescript controllers and the connected html files from a IIS 7 database, but the code has been minimized and divided into .js and .js.min files.

Using chrome source, I've managed to find and use the reconstructed .ts files, but when I try to open the corresponding html files in chrome, they show up blank. 
I have found the html code I need in a `templates.js` file, but it's not formatted as html, but rather in a compressed form;

```
$templateCache.put(" loooong line of html looking code.....");
```

example of compressed html found in `templates.js`

`$templateCache.put("/Project.Dashboards.Instruments/Instruments/XYPlot/xYPlotEdit.html","<form role=form class=xyPlot-edit><div class=form-group><div class=row><div class=col-sm-4><div class=dashboards-propertypanel-navigation-container><abn-tree icon-leaf=icon-leaf icon-expand=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down\" icon-collapse=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up\" expand-level=1 tree-data=vm.configurationNodes tree-control=vm.tree data-on-select=vm.open(branch)></abn-tree></div>..... etc`

**Is there any way to reconstruct this html code to a usable form again?**

I'm not very experienced in source mapping in javascript yet, if that wasn't abundantly clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the compressed form? It's somewhat hard to give tips on reconstructing data if you do not know how it's been compressed down.

Comment: The compressed form is a compressed string of html, but if it helps...
Also, i'm very shure the file was compressed using gulp.

Comment: It sounds like the "compressed" HTML is just all on one line, which is valid HTML which should display fine. https://jsfiddle.net/6jxeubfx/ Unless something else has been done to the HTML, but I can't tell because you hadn't provided any compressed HTML for us to look at.

Comment: Provided a snippet of the compressed html. If it is valid as you say, how can i make it more readable?
I have tried using visual studios "ctrl K + ctrl D" to "prettify" the code, but it had no effect.

Comment: You can use various online "unminify" tools, but I'll retract my previous statement about it being legitimate HTML. Now I've had a look at it, it possesses usages of regex escapes, which gives the indication that it was written with the intention of being parsed. If you unminify and remove the verbose \'s it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I think I've got the file now. Like N.J.Dawson said, all i needed to do was use an online unminifyer to show the template.js content.

I used http://unminify.com/ for anyone else stumbling over this thread. 
Haven't found out if the html works with my own code yet, but if it doesn't I'm pretty sure it's my fault, not the html code.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer. I'm a stickler for unanswered questions ;) Congratulations on progressing through the problem